# How to partial port connect by using interface bundle?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I'm trying to connect DUT's port list with interface by using bundling.
The current problem is that the DUT was implemented with lots of ports. It's almost 1500 more.

I want to connect a partial bundle interface such as i2c interface, ahb interface, axi interface, etc., to DUT().

As you can see below, I made some example.

```
module myDesign ( 
 input clk,
 input data,
 input   i2c_clk,
 output  i2c_data,
 input     ahb_clk,
 output    ahb_data,
 input       axi_clk,
 output      axi_data
 ...
 //over 1500+ ports..
 ...
);
 ...
endmodule

//I made partial interface 
interface i2c_interface;
 logic i2c_clk;
 logic i2c_data;
endinterface

interface ahb_interface;
 logic ahb_clk;
 logic ahb_data;
endinterface

module tb;
...
i2c_interface i2c_if;
ahb_interface ahb_if;

// I want implement to interface bundle 
myDesign u_myDesign ( .*,?); //<=== How Can I connect partial interface by bundling in valid way?
endmodule
```

For your understanding, I also made an example at EDA playground:  https://www.edaplayground.com/x/khdC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not simply connect an interface to the DUT port list because the port **types** must match between the module definition and the module instantiation.  I think you are asking if something like this is possible:

```
myDesign u_myDesign ( i2c_if, ahb_ih );
```

That is illegal because the `myDesign` module does not have ports of type `i2c_interface` and `ahb_interface`.

If you have the option to modify the `myDesign` module, then you could add ports of that type inside the module:

```
module myDesign ( 
 input clk,
 input data,
 i2c_interface i2c_if,
 ahb_interface ahb_if,
 ...
);
```

If you can not change the DUT, then you must make individual connections, as you have shown in the EDA playground link:

```
  adder DUT (
    .a(i_i2c_intf.a),
    .b(i_i2c_intf.b),
    .c(i_i2c_intf.c),
    .a0(i_axi_intf.a0),
    .b0(i_axi_intf.b0),
    .c0(i_axi_intf.c0),
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 25. *Interfaces*.